# How do I get TextMate to use Ruby on Rails by default?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, textmate

How do I make TextMate use the Rails bundle by default? On some files it's enabled, and on others (including models) it's not, and I wish it would just assume that every .rb file is a Ruby on Rails file unless I tell it otherwise.

Is there a project-level or global setting for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to do it at a global level, but you have to edit and view some plist files to make it work. Check out [this site](http://lists.macromates.com/textmate/2006-February/008276.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you have to change the scope selector for each bundle. Maybe TM2 will be different.